# How to program the refactored version of my code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I received a good answer how to refactor my code at codereview.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90378/how-should-i-refactor-my-insert-class/90385#90385

But when I try the code my IDE issues error: `Unresolved reference w` and `']' expected`. What is wrong with the code? I'm still learning python so I'm not sure what the error is, it might be a typo.

```
BAD_WORDS = ['penis', 'black money', 'escort']

if any[w in text or w.upper() in text or w.capitalize() in text
       for w in BAD_WORDS]:
    self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
    return
```

Comment: `any` is a function so you need parentheses around the list comprehension: `if any([w in text or w.upper() in text or w.capitalize() in text
                for w in BAD_WORDS]):`

Comment: @JamesMills the closing square bracket is on the following line

Comment: You are using brackets instead of parentheses.

Comment: `text` is a list, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need parentheses for a function call. Secondly, you can reduce your code to the following:

```
any(w.lower() in text.lower().split() for w in BAD_WORDS)
```

Comment: I'd change `w.lower()` to just `w` and move `map(str.lower, text)` out of the generator expression.

Comment: It's not working. `descriptor 'lower' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'`

Comment: Let me end the review that I started suggesting `any(w.lower() in text.lower() for w in BAD_WORDS)` (calling `lower` more directly and succintly)

Comment: You've failed to tell us what `text` actually is. Please show us it in the question.

Comment: @Caridorc As he hasn't told us what it is, I assumed it was a list.

Comment: The variable text is a string that comes from http post.

Comment: @Caridorc In that case I will just lower then split.

Comment: @Caridorc Using your code from the comment here is working. Thanks!

Comment: @Niklasinstockholm It's the same as what I have except for the split at the words.

Answer (score 2):

[`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) is a function call so you need to wrap parentheses around your list comprehension:

```
BAD_WORDS = ['penis', 'black money', 'escort']

if any(w in text or w.upper() in text or w.capitalize() in text
                for w in BAD_WORDS):
    self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
    return
```

What you had:

```
if any[w in text or w.upper() in text or w.capitalize() in text
                for w in BAD_WORDS]:
```

is invalid

Comment: Actually the square brackets became redundant now.

Comment: You can also reduce code by *lowercasing* everything.

Comment: I'm still getting some error from pyCharm when trying the above code. It says `']' expected` at the end of the `text` word and it is also marking red the square bracket at `BAD_WORDS]`. What is wrong?

Comment: @kirelagin yes that's true, that's a valid point also MalikBahimi